# Magento 1.14.2.1 to Magento 2.3.2 from CLI

Tags: magento, migration, magento2

I am trying to migrate website from Magento 1.14.2.1 to Magento 2.3.2 using Ubuntu commands. I have made all changes on config.xml file with path to both database and here is the command i am trying to execute to apply settings

```
xxx$bin/magento migrate:settings -r vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce/1.14.2.1/config.xml
```

it returns the following error

```
In Dom.php line 455:

EntityRef: expecting ';'
Line: 133

migrate:settings [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] [--] <config>
```

i have tried this as well

```
xxx$bin/magento migrate:settings -reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce/1.14.2.1/config.xml
```

Tried internet but found no help on it, would be great if someone suggest the fix for this error.

Answer (score -1):

You are not able to update magento 1 to magento2 just from command line.

You have to make a whole of data migration.

Magneto has some migration tools also :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool.html